# E-mails per day problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

This is an exam problem from probability and statistics that I failed, and still cannot figure out. Thanks in advance.

The number of e-mails that a person receives in a work day (monday to friday) can be modeled with the poisson distribution with an average of 6 e-mails a day. The number of e-mails a person receives during the weekend can also be modeled with the poisson distribution with an average of 3 e-mails a day.

a) What is the probability that person does not receive any e-mails, if we do not know which day it is?

b) A day is chosen at random from the week. If that person didn't receive a an e-mail on that day, what is the probability that day is a work day?

Comment: Someone will probably come along and write out a solution in a minute or two but you are supposed to make more of an attempt to explain your thinking and working beforehand. It also helps actually get at what you have misunderstood; seeing a perfect solution is not the same as gaining understanding

Comment: I'll do that now.

Comment: As suspected there is already a solution with very little explanation or motivation. Beware trying to actually properly learn the subject like this.

Comment: Please edit your question to share your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Let $p_1=\exp(-6)$ be the probability of receiving $0$ emails on a week-day and $p_2=\exp(-3)$ be the probability of receiving $0$ emails on a weekend (from the definition of a Poisson random variable). If the day of the week is not known (but all days have the same probability), then the probability of receiving $0$ emails is $\tfrac{5}{7}p_1+\tfrac{2}{7}p_2$.

The probability that today is a workday AND no emails were received is $\tfrac{5}{7}p_1$ so the probability that today is a workday given that no emails were received is $\tfrac{\tfrac{5}{7}p_1}{\tfrac{5}{7}p_1+\tfrac{2}{7}p_2}$.

Comment: Do you know any sites with practice problems for probability and statistics?

Comment: No. It also depends on your syllabus, there are many possible topics in "probability and statistics"